# jQuery .getJSON() twitter search, result is undefined.

Tags: jquery, twitter, getjson

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#hit').click(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=stackoverflow&callback=?", function(data) {
            alert(data.length);
        });
      });  // #button hit click evnet
});  // document ready
```

result is undefined.

[image]

I navigate the api call manually in browser, it does return me the data.

[image]

Why result is undefined with my jQuery getJSON call?

Comment: pretty sure you are doing a cross domain request,  unless you are working for twitter :)

Comment: @KeithNicholas jQuery is smart enough to switch to JSONP when there's a "callback=?" query parameter.

Comment: @KeithNicholas   I have '&callback=?' in the call

Comment: no worries... just didn't realise jquery did that! very nice :)

Comment: It's often best to use `console.log(data);` instead of `alert(data)`. Webkits Inspector (Ctrl-Shift-I or right-click inspect-element) or FireBug will show a smart object and let you drill down into it in the console.

Comment: `console.dir` is also cool...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=stackoverflow&callback=?", function(data) {
     alert(Object.keys(data).length);
 });
```

The returned `data` is an object and not an array, so `data.length` is undefined.

But above procedure is not supported for all browsers. So you can try:

```
data.results.length
```

To check that if a key is present in an object (if you're not sure) it's better to use:

```
if( "key" in object) {

}
```

For you case:

```
if( "results" in data) {

}
```

if your query become invalid twitter will response with an error object so to confirm about successful query result you can use:

```
if("error" in data) {

}
```

There is another process called [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty)

```
if(data.hasOwnProperty("results")) {

}
```

Comment: still don't get it. as getJSON callback function use the 'data' as parameter represents the result.  why we need the Object.keys(data)?

Comment: The issue with this answer is that `Object.keys` may not be supported across all browsers yet. Try `alert(data.results.length)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the payload that's returned, the actual results are inside a property called `results`. So, try:

```
alert(data.results.length)
```